# HTML|JS|CSS framework/library that works with PhoneGap and major browsers

Tags: html, cordova, mobile, cross-browser, cross-platform

We have a requirement to build app with as much common codebase as possible, that works on desktop and mobile platforms (Android, iOS, Windows Phone). Also, the app on mobile platforms should act like an app (so not mobile-friendly website), with access to camera, position, and an icon.

Having looked at all the options and finding some or the other quirks, I decided on having webapp/site on browser and PhoneGap to base the mobile app on.

Now, as far as my understanding goes, sticking the codebase of browser webapp/site in Phonegap base structure should work for the mobile app. Of course, some minor changes may be warranted.

However, I also saw that relying only on phonegap and barebones HTML5 tech (without any UI framework) would need a lot of time and would be tiresome.

So I looked around for a UI framework and found - JQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch, Kendo UI, etc. jQuery Mobile, while could work in desktop browsers too, would not give me a grid-like system to position elements. The rest of them seem to work only on mobile platforms - they did not boast about it working/scaling on desktop browsers.

So, is there any common library/framework that can provide - CSS animations, grid-like system for positioning, etc.?

Comment: Ionic framework is another interesting option! http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: @jcarrera They have a rather dicey support for desktop browsers though.

Comment: Ext JS 6 does everything you're asking for... but this question is going to get nothing but opinions for replies (like mine!) ...and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and verifications on browser and phonegap, I chose the following combination:

- **Yahoo's purecss** library for grid system and basic widgets. Its awesome with the only pain that Google Search on it gives ambiguous results.
- **Reactjs** to manage the view logic. This was the biggest pain in my previous project having only used jQuery, turning my whole project into a huge jQuery soup. React is extremely clean compared to that.
- **superagent** probably, for AJAX requests to fetch server data. Extending this, I haven't yet decided to employ a **model-like library** that handles the state; may be I dont need one. I will decide as the project moves on.
- **hand-coded CSS** with some common sense so that I learn something and dont waste my time in finding an all-in-one library. _The only necessary rule here is to weed out older best practices when you are looking for something. For example, in order to center something, the `transition` method is the best technique.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an "answer" so much as an idea for a method. Perhaps try creating what you need from a desktop perspective first using bootstrap so it's mobile first. Then maybe make use of something like jquery mobile for the bare bones navigation and structure in the app. You can then pull in your page content via ajax using the same code/layouts from your "desktop version" (which will of course have a mobile friendly view/layout since it's written using bootstrap).

You'll likely have to either create an api for serving up the content for your app or else find some other way to differentiate the app from the desktop site on the server side so you know where they request is coming from, but it seems do able.